# How do I set a MysQL variable (time_zone) from within doctrine / symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I would like to know how I can set the MySQL time zone to UTC (`SET time_zone = 'UTC'`) from within Symfony/Doctrine, so when I call a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function on a `DATETIME` field in my query, it returns the UTC unix time and not unix time in the server's time zone.

How can I do this, either automatically upon every connection, or manually before these types of queries where the timezone makes a difference?

BTW, I need to do this conversion within the MySQL query and not the app so I can `GROUP BY` an interval that requires epoch time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via the `configureDoctrineConnection` callbacks that gets called in ProjectConfiguration`:

```
public function configureDoctrineConnection(Doctrine_Connection $connection)
{
  $connection->exec('SET time_zone = "UTC"');
}
```

There may be issues with this if you're using multiple connections.

*(Answer edited to remove additonal method that was flawed.)*

Comment: The first gives an error "there is no open connection in ...", but the second one works great, thanks. Note: I guess "UTC" isn't a valid time zone on my machine at least, so I changed it to "+0:00".

Answer (score 1):

I would try editing the projectConfiguration, and add something like (untested and unverified):

```
    $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
    $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();
    $diff = $connection->execute("SET time_zone = 'UTC'");
```

Note, `$options` and `$this->configuration` is only available in a task, so maybe this should be hardcoded (I believe default is `'doctrine'`).

Comment: Not working out of the box and I don't know enough about Symfony to troubleshoot it very well ($this->configuration is empty in this context..)

Comment: Solutions provided here do not have to be working out of the box; I only pointed you in the right direction for finding an answer (which would be jeremy's in this case).

Comment: I didn't meant to imply they did, only that I didn't spend much time troubleshooting it (because there was another answer that worked immediately). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this at the Symfony application level, the way is adding this to the `config/settings.yml`

```
all:
  .settings:
    default_culture: en_US
    default_timezone: Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: Can you add the documentation link as well please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the answer **not on MySQL, but on Oracle DB**.
I searched for data on Oracle DB for a long time, but found nothing.
This is the only topic that also discusses the problem, but only in MySQL.

Perhaps, someone will help, for Oracle DB:

In file `config/services.yaml`

For Symofony 4:

```
services:
    Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit:
        arguments:
            - TIME_ZONE: 'UTC'
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

For Symfony 2 and 3:

```
services:
    oci8.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        arguments:
            - TIME_ZONE: 'UTC'
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

Or, you can write the arguments object to yaml as:

```
arguments: { TIME_ZONE: 'UTC' }
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8 and Symfony 5, you can add the following to `config/services.yaml`

```
services:
    Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\SQLSessionInit:
        arguments:
            - 'SET TIME_ZONE="+04:00"'
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```